# Error while opening socket to dev1.wso2.in:9712. Connection timed out

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I might have reconfigured some ports and i am getting below error.
How to fix this? Its wso2 am 2.0.0 and preconfigured identity server

```
2017-11-29 04:17:29,407 [-] [DataBridge-ConnectionService-tcp://dev1.wso2.in:9612-pool-7-thread-1] ERROR DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://dev1.wso2.in:9712
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://dev1.wso2.in:9712
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointException: Error while opening socket to dev1.wso2.in:9712. Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:92)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
```

Comment: Do you have a distributed deployment?

Comment: Nope. I am using WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 Identity server combo.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have one node API Manager, port 9712 should be blocked. API Manager needs this port for throttling purposes.

Comment: How to fix it? how can i figure it out?